# Merge multiple list with intersection and add the items

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have the list of lists:

```
[[2, 15.0], [3, 15.0], [1, 20.0], [3, 18.0], [1, 50.0, u'pass'], [2, 10.0, u'fail'], [3, 30.0, u'pass']]
```

I want to merge this list together which have the same first element

The example solution is like this

```
[[1, 50.0, u'pass',20.0], [2, 10.0, u'fail',15,0], [3, 30.0, u'pass',15.0,18.0]]
```

Is that even possible?
If possible could you give me ideas please or how should it be?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried

Comment: i couldn't do anything helpful , i feel like my brain smashed by hamer

Comment: In what order should they be merged?

Comment: order not constrains  but it should merge all lists with the same first element and the first element shouldn't be repeated after merge operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order does not matter you can try

```
>>> l = [[2, 15.0], [3, 15.0], [1, 20.0], [3, 18.0], [1, 50.0, u'pass'], [2, 10.0, u'fail'], [3, 30.0, u'pass']]
>>> temp = {}
>>> for i in l:
...      if i[0] in temp:
...            temp[i[0]].extend(i[1:])
...      else:
...            temp[i[0]] = i[1:]
... 
>>> temp
{1: [20.0, 50.0, u'pass'], 2: [15.0, 10.0, u'fail'], 3: [15.0, 18.0, 30.0, u'pass']}
>>> new_l = [[i]+temp[i] for i in temp]
>>> new_l
[[1, 20.0, 50.0, u'pass'], [2, 15.0, 10.0, u'fail'], [3, 15.0, 18.0, 30.0, u'pass']]
```

Here you create a dictionary and put the numbers as keys. After that you add the list as values to those keys. Finally you can get the desired output using a list comprehension

Code -

```
l = [[2, 15.0], [3, 15.0], [1, 20.0], [3, 18.0], [1, 50.0, u'pass'], [2, 10.0, u'fail'], [3, 30.0, u'pass']]
temp = {}
for i in l:
    if i[0] in temp:
          temp[i[0]].extend(i[1:])
    else:
          temp[i[0]] = i[1:]
new_l = [[i]+temp[i] for i in temp]
```

Comment: Thanks,that was helpful

Comment: @MostafaMohamed Glad to be of help. All the best.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a combination of `itertools.groupby` and `itertools.chain`

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter


def combine_and_flatten(original, key=0):
    # Key is the index of the field to merge the lists by.
    for _, groups in itertools.groupby(sorted(original, key=itemgetter(key), itemgetter(key)):
        yield itertools.chain(*b)
```

Comment: i Like your answer and it's prefect but i would like to keep it simple :D

Answer (score 1):

got this working, maps/dictionaries will do the trick

```
a = [[2, 15.0],
    [3, 15.0],
    [1, 20.0],
    [3, 18.0],
    [1, 50.0, u'pass'],
    [2, 10.0, u'fail'],
    [3, 30.0, u'pass']
]

b = {x: [] for x,*y in a}

print('initial empty map : ',b)
print()

for x,*y in a:
    for z in y:
        if z not in b[x]:
            b[x].append(z)

print('filled up map: ', b)
print()

# now creating a combined list

final_list = [[x] + y for x,y in b.items()]

print('required list: ', final_list)
```

you can try the solution here [on repl.it](https://repl.it/B2Ya)

> ouput

```
required list:  [[1, 20.0, 50.0, 'pass'], [2, 15.0, 10.0, 'fail'], [3, 15.0, 18.0, 30.0, 'pass']]
```

Comment: x, *y notation is special way of tuple assignment  
like `x, *y = [1,2,3,4]` will give `x=1` and `y=[2,3,4]`
search for `tuple argument packing/unpacking` in python